# Chamar uma função com base na struct passada na referencia?

Tags: c++, funções, struct

Como Faço para chamar a função menu passando mais de um struct por referencia de acordo com a validação na função validacao ?

desculpa eu estou começando agora e decidi fazer esse pequeno exercicio para praticar funcões, classes, e structs e me deparei com esse problema que nao consigo resolver. Alguem pode me ajudar por favor ?

```
class Conta {

 private:


struct cliente_1 {
    string nome = "Odair";
    int conta = 739146;
    double senha = 759247;
    float saldo = 00.00;
    double cpf = 48730701875;
};

struct cliente_2 {
    string nome = "Leo";
    int conta = 135478;
    double senha = 789878;
    float saldo = 00.00;
    double cpf = 48730701875;
};


struct cliente_3 {
    string nome = "Caio";
    int conta = 789757;
    double senha = 24860165;
    float saldo = 00.00;
    double cpf = 48730701875;
};

struct clientes {

    cliente_1 c1;
    cliente_2 c2;
    cliente_3 c3;

};
 public:

void menu( cliente_1 cont) {


    cout << cont.nome << endl;
    system("pause");




}
void validacao(int x, double  y) {

    cliente_1 c1;
    cliente_1 c2;
    cliente_1 c3;


    if (x == 739396 || y == 759247) {

        menu(c1);
    }
    else if (x == 135478 || y == 789878) {

        menu(c2);
    }
    else if (x == 789757 || y == 24860165) {

        menu(c3);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de suas 3 `struct` ter exatamente o mesmo formato, elas estão declaradas como sendo diferentes então você não vai conseguir passar elas para a sua função, o compilador vai acusar como erro.

Você pode criar uma Struct única e depois criar 3 instância dela.

```
struct Cliente {
    string nome;
    int conta;
    double senha;
    float saldo;
    double cpf;
};

Cliente c1, c2, c3;

// adiciona os valores aos Structs antes de começar a modificalos
void IniciarClientes()
{
    c1.nome = "Odair";
    c1.conta = 739146;
    c1.senha = 759247;
    c1.saldo = 00.00;
    c1.cpf = 48730701875;

    c2.nome = "Leo";
    // e continua o restante
}

// passando como referencia como você pediu na pergunta
void menu(Cliente *cliente) 
{
    cout << cliente->nome << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void validacao(int x, double  y)
{
    if (x == 739396 || y == 759247) 
    {
        // passando como referencia
        menu(&c1);
    }
    else if (x == 135478 || y == 789878) 
    {
        menu(&c2);
    }
    else if (x == 789757 || y == 24860165)
    {
        menu(&c3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeuuuuu vou tentar ...

Comment: pode me dar mais uma ajudinha, eu fiz da forma que vc me ensinou porem, algo no cout nao exibe nada na tela, é como se pulasse o cout e fosse direto pro system pause.

Comment: se você adicionar mais alguma coisa no `cout` junto com `cliente->nome` exibe?

Comment: Não, porém quando coloco pra exibir outro dado double ou float invés do nome aparece uns número meio nada a ver tipo - 946856x84

Comment: você inicializou as `struct` com o `IniciarClientes()`

Comment: Sim e chamei ela tanto no int main quanto na função valifacao

Comment: Fiz um teste rapido aqui, aparentemente o problema é a `string` dentro da `struct`, muda para `char*`